# Jenkins Slack integration, but can't find post-build action

Tags: jenkins

I want to use the Slack plugin in Jenkins to ping notifications to a Slack channel.

Jenkins says success when I test the connection, and I saw that connect was successful.

And after that, I need to add to Jenkins job configurations and add a post-build action on each job that you wish to ping the slack channel.

But I can't find post-build action in Job's configure.

Jenkins has version 2.121.3.

Comment: You mean you don't see the post-build action section or you dont see "Slack notification" in post-build option list?

Comment: Yes, I mean that can't  see the post-build action section.

Answer (score 0):

What kind of job configuration are you using ? Freestyle ? Multibranch ? Pipeline ? It's likely that the post-build actions will not appear for every kind of Jenkins job/project. 
If you create a new job (New Item > Freestyle project), you should see the option at the end.

Comment: Good advice, but i using Pipeline!

Comment: Same problem, I'm on Jenkins version 2.204.5 using Pipeline with a Jenkinsfile.  Test of Slack Notification plugin in Jenkins returned success.  I had thought this would be specified in the Pipeline => Additional Behaviors list, but haven't found it there yet.